# app name look strange on device

Tags: java, android

i have cut my app name in two parts using a line break so my name will appear on two lines under the icon in the program list, like this:

`<string name="app_name">Munspel\nAppen</string>`

This works well on the emulator, and on a samsung galaxy where i am testing my application. However, when I install it on my old device Godroid V.5 android version 2.2.2 it will show a square character, ¤, right after the first name. Like this: Munspel¤ There are other programs with similare line break cuts as I have in the list that shows the name normally without the ¤ character, so I am certain it should be possible to find a solution how to remove this. Anyone got any ideas? I have specifically made my app for android versions API 8, 2.2, so it seems strange this happens...
All help is appreciated...
Andreas

Answer (score 2):

Disable the default title bar of the app, and use your own two textviews layout to display the words separately. That way you do not have to worry about different devices. Also you can make the app name textviews to be more inline with the app's theme.

[This link](http://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/03/18/android-dynamic-and-custom-title-bars/) tells how to create custom title bars.

Comment: thanks for answer, i have disabled the bar, i dont quite follow you how to make two text-views. Should i make one xml file containing the two views and then reference android:label to that in my manifest? some code example for a novice programmer would be welcomed...

Comment: @Andreas I have included a link in my answer which tells how to create custom title bars. Its easy

Comment: this would appear to apply to the activity's own screens, not the label on its launcher icon.

Answer (score 1):

The launcher app ultimately decides how to display your app name, so you can't really rely on any specific behaviour. If decided to show line breaks with some character (or the font they use does so), there is not much you can do. Simply don't use a line break in your app name, and let the launcher handle it.

Comment: it's not only an answer, it's the correct answer as far as launcher presentation of icons is concerned.

Comment: Funny though many other apps in the app list have proper double name with line breaks, guess they write their code in a different way..?

Comment: The probably are simply using a regular space to separate words, and the launcher decides to break the text on two lines if there is not enough space. This your best bet too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new line, try \r\n like this: Munspel\r\nAppen

Comment: There is a solution, to fill out the first part of the name with space characters, until it breaks into two lines. Question is, would this break due to filling up with spaces be the same on different devices....?